# Return related user id in cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm looking to return the users' node id from the query. Ideally that id would be paired as a property with each of the returned users but could also come as an array of corresponding id's of the returned users.

Here's the current query

```
var query = [
    'MATCH (f:FundRaiser)<-[t:TRANSACTION]-(u:User)',
    'WHERE ID(f) ='+ fundraiserId,
    'RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT u)as users,COLLECT(DISTINCT t) as transactions'
].join('\n');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query string should produce a result in which `users` would be a collection of distinct objects, each containing a `User` node and its native `ID`.

```
var query = [
    'MATCH (f:FundRaiser)<-[t:TRANSACTION]-(u:User)',
    'WHERE ID(f) ='+ fundraiserId,
    'RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT {u: u, id: ID(u)}) as users, COLLECT(DISTINCT t) as transactions'
].join('\n');
```

NOTE: You should pass the `fundraiserId` value as a [parameter](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/), which would be more secure and performant.